# How do I check that a configuration file has been read?

Tags: sshd

It seems that modifications to my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file are not picked up by the SSH daemon. For test purposes, I included a `DenyUsers *`, did `service ssh restart`, and even rebooted the whole system. But I still can ssh from remote.

How can I check that the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file gets read by `sshd`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am not sure if a program reads a specific config file (or in which order), I try to trace the open syscalls with `strace`. To do this stop the ssh daemon. Then start it manually in the terminal by:

```
strace -e open -ostrace.out /usr/sbin/sshd
```

After it has started you should have a file in your current working directory called `strace.out`. In my case it looked like this (output stripped down):

```
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
...
many libraries
...
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3
open("/dev/null", O_RDWR)               = 3
open("/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/etc/ssh/sshd_config", O_RDONLY)  = 3 <--- here sshd_config was opened
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
open("/etc/gai.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
...
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
...
ssh keys
...
open("/etc/ssh/blacklist.ECDSA-256", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

With this test I can make sure `sshd` reads my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. In the last entry you can see that this file is not found on my system (-1).

Comment: That helped a lot. It pointed me to the embarrassing error that I modified `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` instead of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Thanks.